# Mysql replication with UPDATE JOIN on an ignored table

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm doing mysql replication and as a dumbed down example, I have two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`.

on the slave for replication, `tableA` is allowed and `tableB` is ignored.

```
replicate-do-table='dbname.tableA'
```

On the master, this query is being made (i can't make any changes to the master):

```
UPDATE tableA as a LEFT JOIN tableB as b ON b.type = a.type
SET b.col1 = CONCAT(IFNULL(a.col1,''),'|',IFNULL(a.col2,''))
```

Obviously I could just create `tableB` on the slave and let it update a bogus table, however this table in particular is an in-memory table that is used for searching and is updated almost constantly resulting in a lot of wasted resources.

Is there a way for me to filter out these updates from the replication while still keeping `tableA`? I have no access to the master, however i can ask them to make changes if it's a change that wouldn't affect how their system operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation it made more sense to instead ignore the table doesn't exist errors. It is because my database system has little to no chance of ever changing and the updates in question never target the tables I am replicating.

It is a legacy system that we're slowly moving away from.

```
slave-skip-errors=1146
```

The only other reliable way to solve this would be to switch to row-level bin logging on the master, however I couldn't get them to make that change for me.

Answer (score 10):

Options AFAIK are mainly based around getting the replication to be be `ROW` based rather then `STATEMENT` based.

1. Set the default to `ROW` (which is a brute force method, and has its drawbacks).
2. [You can set the `SESSION` binlog_format to `ROW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-setting.html), but it requires the `SUPER` privilege which the user probably hasn't and will not be granted either for good reasons.
3. If the logging happens in `MIXED` format [you can look around here to force a `ROW` based entry in the binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-mixed.html), trying to force a useless `FOUND_ROWS()` or  `UUID()` call in the update could very well trigger it.

An example for the `MIXED` solution:
The queries:

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('a','aa');
UPDATE sometable SET aa='bb';
UPDATE sometable SET aa='cc' WHERE UUID(); -- slight overhead, but always true
```

The log (use mysqlbinlog to inspect it), clearly `STATEMENT` based for the first 2, but `ROW` based for the 3rd:

```
# at 175
#130918 21:18:25 server id 1  end_log_pos 277   Query   thread_id=142   exec_time=0     error_code=0
use `test`/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1379531905/*!*/;
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('a','aa')
/*!*/;
# at 277
#130918 21:18:25 server id 1  end_log_pos 304   Xid = 488
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 304
#130918 21:18:52 server id 1  end_log_pos 372   Query   thread_id=142   exec_time=0     eror_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1379531932/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 372
#130918 21:18:52 server id 1  end_log_pos 463   Query   thread_id=142   exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1379531932/*!*/;
UPDATE sometable SET aa='bb'
/*!*/;
# at 463
#130918 21:18:52 server id 1  end_log_pos 490   Xid = 497
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 490
#130918 21:21:06 server id 1  end_log_pos 558   Query   thread_id=144   exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1379532066/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 558
# at 610
#130918 21:21:06 server id 1  end_log_pos 610   Table_map: `test`.`sometable` mapped to number 180
#130918 21:21:06 server id 1  end_log_pos 664   Update_rows: table id 180 flags: STMT_END_F
BINLOG '
Iv05UhMBAAAANAAAAGICAAAAALQAAAAAAAEABHRlc3QACXNvbWV0YWJsZQAC/A8DAwYAAQ==
Iv05UhgBAAAANgAAAJgCAAAAALQAAAAAAAEAAv///QJiYv0CY2P8AQAAYQJiYvwBAABhAmNj
'/*!*/;
# at 664
#130918 21:21:06 server id 1  end_log_pos 691   Xid = 578
COMMIT/*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
```